# Sabre queue reading error

Tags: php, sabre

I want to reach queue in sabre. You know, using 2 request at QueueAccessLLSRQ. Access and navigation.

I am using QueueIdentifier(Access method) in first method and response ok. Showing pnrs in the queue.

I want to remove all pnrs in queue. But I am getting an error at navigation method. How can I handle this error?

```
REQUEST
<ns1:QueueAccessRQ ReturnHostCommand="false" Version="2.0.8"><ns1:Navigation>
<ns1:Direction Action="E" Plus="176"/>
</ns1:Navigation></ns1:QueueAccessRQ>

RESPONSE
<QueueAccessRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.8">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
  <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-02-07T00:59:28-06:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message>CANNOT DO THIS IF OFF QUEUE</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
</QueueAccessRS>
```

Comment: I solved it when it changed the request. List Ind="true" it isn't using access queue. and navigation action parameter should be "QR". direction remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all PNRs at once, you cannot use this service, but you ca use SabreCommandLLSRQ, sending the command `QCL/1` where 1 should be replaced by the queue number.

You can use QueueAccessRQ with the QR Action, but you'll have to remove one by one each PNR. But before you can do QR, you have to do `<QueueIdentifier Number="1">` to get IN the queue.

Because the error you got there `CANNOT DO THIS IF OFF QUEUE` means that you need to be in the queue before you can do queue actions.